# How to load new resources into pixi.js app after resources were already loaded?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have json file that contains list of files that should be loade, how to achieve this with PIXI?

**// THIS IS FIRST LOAD OF RESOURCES**

```
this.app.loader
    .add("bin", "ui/" + "bin.png")
    .add("rotatecw", "ui/" + "rotatecw.png")
    .add("rotateccw", "ui/" + "rotateccw.png")
    ...

    .add("categorieConfigJson", "config/allCategoriesConfig.json");

 this.app.loader.load();
 this.app.loader.onComplete.add((event) => this.onLoadComplete(//and here inside I am doing the main logic));
```

As you see there is one `allCategoriesConfig.json` file. It contains some game configuration as well as additional list of files that should be loaded. In future here will be some `AJAX` call to backend and backend will send `json`, but for now it is `json` file.
So now in Pixi App I have to parse this file and load additionall resources. So how to do this if I already did `this.app.loader.load()`?

Assume that in onLoadComplete I have parsed my json file and loaded list of newly necessary files into variable categoriesConfig. The questions is - if I have already loaded all resources using this.app.loader and load(), how, can I add more files there???

**// THIS IS CALLED AFTER RESOURCES ARE LOADED, AND HERE I NEED TO LOAD ADDITIONAL RESOURCES**

```
private onLoadComplete2() 
{
    // parse json file and get file names into categoriesConfig array

    // and now need to load additional resources, how?
    categoriesConfig.forEach(fileName => {
       // how to add fileName to already loaded this.app.loader?
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

So you should create a new loader for this second round of loading, since the loader is not meant for managing resources.

If you want to reuse this instance, you can call `loader.reset()` before adding and loading new resources. But bear in mind that on the `load` callback, the old resources won't be there anymore.

Read the [loader's philosophy](https://github.com/englercj/resource-loader#philosophy):

> [...] your project should have a Resource Manager that stores resources and manages data lifetime. When it decides something needs to be loaded from a remote source, only then does it create a loader and load them.

#### How to use

```js
// This collects all loaded resources.
const allResources = {}

this.app.loader.add( /* statically known stuff */ )
this.app.loader.add('dynamicResourcesJson', ...)

this.app.loader.load((loader, resources) => {
  // Store the loaded resources
  Object.assign(allResources, resources)

  // Reset the loader or create a new one
  loader.reset()
  // or `loader = new PIXI.Loader()`

  // Enqueue the new resources
  const newResources = JSON.parse(resources['dynamicResourcesJson'].data)
  for(const [name, url] of Object.entries(newResources)) {
    loader.add(name, url)
  }

  loader.load((loader, resources) => {
    // Store the loaded resources
    Object.assign(allResources, resources)
  })
})
```

Comment: If I will use new loader, will all resources be available? 
And I didn't get this "philosophy"unfourtunately, I am new to PIXI.JS, this is first project. The loader you have references - how it is related to Pixi?

Comment: The [PIXI.Loader](https://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Loader.html) is based on it. The resources won't be available. You have to store them yourself. Like it states: "It is **not** a goal of this library to be a resource caching and management system, just a loader." I'll update my answer with a code snippet.

Comment: Still I do not get - if I reset loader then I will loose my resources. Ok, even if loader is not created for resources, I do not understand how to store them wihtin my Pixi application. I need all resources - during first load and second one.

Comment: I've updated the example. I hope it helps you.